# Ionic - Typescript error - Type is not an array or a string

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I am starting with Ionic and Angular and I am facing an issue with variable type. 
I am querying an API that ouput an array of elements.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import  {PostService } from '../_providers/post-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers:[PostService]
})
export class HomePage {
  public posts: any;
  private start:number=0;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public postService: PostService) {
    this.getPost();
  }
  getPost(){
    return new Promise(
      resolve => {
        this.postService.load(this.start)
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          for(let post of data) {
            this.posts.push(post);
          }
          resolve(true);
        });
      });
}

  doInfinite(infiniteScroll:any) {
   console.log(this.start);
   this.start+=10;
   this.getPost().then(()=>{
       infiniteScroll.complete();
     });
 }

  likePost(post){
    post.likes++;
  }

}
```

Line 23, I have this issue: 
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnK9A.png)

And the console.log returns: 
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x4rP.png)

Finally, the PostService class looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PostService {

  perpage:number = 10;

  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  load(start:number=0) {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      this.http.get('http://api.voyonsvoir.fr/?[limit]='+this.perpage+'&filter[skip]='+start)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          resolve(data.posts);

        });
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Initialise your posts array to be empty to begin with. Try something other than for..of, try for..in or the javascript forEach see if those work.

Comment: Thanks rrd. Would this be the right way to declare an empty array   public posts: string[];  > 
Also when I try to use forEach I have this error: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type {}

Comment: Actually the for..in did work. But for(let post in data) returns me only the array key and no the content

Comment: I did something ugly from my point of view :  
`getPost(){
    return new Promise(
      resolve => {
        this.postService.load(this.start)
        .then(data => {
          for(let post in data) {
            this.posts.push(data[post]);
          }
          resolve(true);
        });
      });
}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some types, both here:

```
public posts: any[] = [];
```

And then the return from the service method:

```
load(start:number=0): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise<any[]>(resolve => {
```

Note: it would be better to be more specific than `any`, but it should get it at least running.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I've added the public post line. Not sure what to do with the greet() fonction. Are you refering to PostService class file or my HomePage class file ?

Comment: Sorry, I must have had a copy/paste artefact:

`load(): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise<any[]>(resolve => {`

However,

Comment: The core problem is TypeScript doesn't know that the promise in your function resolves to an array, so it has no idea that `data` is an array. If you annotate up the load function, it should be fine.